# iMac and RAM upgrade for a new iMac?

Tags: imac

I wanted to buy [this](http://www.adorama.com/ACME089LLAUZ.html) iMac. Does anyone know if I could upgrade the RAM to 16?

Comment: Apple iMac 27" LED All-in-One Desktop Computer, Intel Core i7 Quad-Core 3.5GHz, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M

Comment: Yes, up to 32 Gig, but what is it with the Mavericks ? it suppose to have Yosemite ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 likely a product page that wasn't updated. wouldn't matter since the Yosemite upgrade is free.

Comment: @EthanLee I know that Yosemite is Free, my question was why this "brand new model" does not have it?

Comment: @Buscar웃 like I said, outdated product pictures and/or model in stock by the third-party referenced. Apple's latest are imaged with Yosemite when sold.

Comment: I would negotiate free memory upgrade since it does not have latest (Yosemite) OS. We know Yosemite is free, but it shows it is a inventory item (sitting on they shelf's since 2013 and collecting dust).

Comment: @Buscar웃 doubtful that this would work. From a resellers' standpoint that has no technical difference. They are selling the same computer, and the only difference is resolved upon setup when the user is prompted to upgrade software. I did happen upon the same model with 16GB RAM on the site, however, without the AppleCare bundled (seems like you can add third-party warranty options to any item, though): http://www.adorama.com/ACME089LLA11.html

Answer (score 1):

This particular model that you're looking at is referring to the Late 2013 model of the iMac, 27" display version (model number ME089LLAUZ from the linked store page and verifiable through Apple's own [KB article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201634)).

Apple sells this on their store still, and you can order a custom configuration with up to 32 GB of RAM as specified on its [product page.](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/imac) This would probably be the better option after a glance at the numbers when you add 16 GB of RAM to the order.

However, for the model on the website you referred to, you can also purchase supported RAM yourself and install it in the two empty slots at the bottom of the machine (Apple has their own [guide for that here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204687)). Note that the RAM you purchase must meet the following criteria (may seem like a lot, but compatible parts are easily found on Amazon and other suppliers):

- PC3-12800
- Unbuffered
- Nonparity
- 204-pin
- 1600 MHz
- DDR3 SDRAM

Comment: @user123287 No problem! If you found this answer sufficient to answer your question, feel free to mark it as correct to help other users with similar questions.